# ActionBar setIcon centered

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to use `actionBar.setIcon()` and have it centered. is this possible?

Already tried using a custom view but the container doesn't get centered.

Comment: Check this answr http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898887/1383427 , and change the TextView to ImageView and use it without Home Button

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I just overrided the `Gravity` property in the custom style

```
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the custom layout,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/ActionBartest"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   >
   <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/slideMenuButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/icon"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Put this in your code,

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    View andView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(andView);
```

Comment: Mark as answer if it has helped you!

Comment: is this the custom view for the ActionBar itself? so for each tab I'd just use actionBar.setIcon?

Comment: Tried this method, but the icon set by "setIcon" is still aligned to the left